# How to increment multiple loops properly in C#

Tags: c#, json, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I am running into a problem where I am not comparing the correct data points because only part of my test is iterating.

```
            //for each row from csv
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in csvDataTable.Rows)
            {
                //for each cell from csv row
                foreach (var csvItem in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    //for each audiogram
                    for (int i = 0; i < audioGramData.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        //for each stimulus frequency
                        for (int e = 0; e < audioGramData.Count(); e++)
                        {
                            string stimLevel = audioGramData[i].ToList()[e]["StimulusLevel"].ToString();

                            if (csvItem.ToString() != stimLevel)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
```

The first pass of the test properly compares the first cell from a csv file to a the proper field from a JSON object.  However, on the second pass, only the stimLevel variable is incremented.

If there were 3 rows in the CSV file, 3 columns in the CSV file, and 3 stimLevels in the JSON object, the flow of the test should be like this:

((Compare first csvItem to first stimLevel

csvItem++

stimLevel++)x3

DataRow++

audiogram++)x3

The audioGramData 2D array is created by first converting a dataTable containing JSON into a JSON object like this:

```
        sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDataTable);
        Conn.Close();
        JObject someObject = JObject.Parse(sqlDataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());

        var audioGramData = (JArray)someObject["HIMSAAudiometricStandard"]["ToneThresholdAudiogram"];
```

Comment: Where are you getting `audioGramData` from?

Comment: The audioGramData 2D array is created by first converting a dataTable containing JSON into a JSON object.  (code added to question).

Comment: this is a case where using linq would completely eliminate a lot of redundant `ToList()` calls...  There isn't enough sample data shown here to know the data structure, but I cringe whenever I see `ToList()[1].ToList()[0].ToList()[e]`  Tells me that we are deep inside a loop but operating against data that is way outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: The issue is currently that I am iterating through the JSON data properly but I am not iterating through the CSV field from the 2nd while loop.  I think I should get rid of the JSON array part of the code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by getting rid of the two extra 4 loops and iterating i and e outside of each of the for each loops.

```
int i =0;
int e =0;               

            //for each row from csv
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in csvDataTable.Rows)
            {
                //for each cell from csv row
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    string stimlevel = audioGramData[i].ToList()[1].ToList()[0].ToList()[e]["StimulusLevel"].ToString();
                    stimlevel = stimlevel.Remove(stimlevel.Length -2);
                    if (item.ToString() != stimlevel)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    e++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return true;
```